# Vue js : custom input clear value

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created a custom input

```
<template>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            <slot></slot>
        </p>
        <input v-model="content" class="textbox" :type="type" @input="handleInput">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'vTextbox',
  props:{
      type: String,
  }, 
  data: function(){
      return {
          content: ""
      }
  },
  methods:{
        handleInput(){
          this.$emit('input', this.content)
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent component call the custom input component to grab its content such as:

```
<vTextbox v-model="email" type="email">Email</vTextbox>
```

```
export default {
  ...
  data: function(){
      return{
          email: "",
      }
  },
  methods:{
    Clear: function(){
        this.email = ""
    }
  }
}
```

I want to clear value/content of my custom input component when Clear function is called. I try to set this.email="" but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that you're not receiving the value in the custom input. While you have `v-model` in the parent component, for the `v-model` magic to work the component needs to implement the `value` prop and watch for `change`.

Here is what that might look like

```
<template>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
            <slot></slot>
        </p>
        <input v-model="content" class="textbox" :type="type" @input="handleInput">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'vTextbox',
  props:{
      value: String, // added value prop
      type: String,
  }, 
  data: function(){
      return {
          content: ""
      }
  },
  watch:{
    value(val) {
      this.content = val; // added watch to override internal value, this will allow clear to work
    }
  },
  methods:{
        handleInput(){
          this.$emit('input', this.content)
      }
  }
}
</script>
```